# Closed-form of $\int_0^{{z^{ - \delta }}} {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + {t^{ - \frac{ 1}{\delta} }}} \right)}^{i + 1}}}}} \right)} dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

Can the following definite integral be solved in closed-form? $$\int_0^{{z^{ - \delta }}} {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + {t^{ - \frac{ 1}{\delta} }}} \right)}^{i + 1}}}}} \right)} dt,$$ where $z\ge 0$, $0<\delta<1$, $i=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.

Comment: I wonder if you can avoid hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici For rational $\delta$, the integral can be reduced to elementary functions. Otherwise, hypergeometric functions seem unavoidable to me (except for the very special cases $z=0$ or $i=0$ of course).